# Create H2O Sparkling-Water app in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, h2o, sparkling-water

I want to set up a Sparkling-Water app in IntelliJ. I found the droplet for a project at: [Sparkling-Water-Droplet](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-droplets/tree/master/sparkling-water-droplet)

But this has not been touched for a year and I was wondering whether there is a more recent version or any other template with newer version numbering for Spark, Scala and Sparkling-Water.

Thanks in Advance for any Hints!

Comment: Maybe this Scala plugin will be helpful: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1347-scala?

Comment: @dnks23 just updated the answer, hopefully you are good to go now.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

The Sparkling Water Droplets were just updated as of a few hours ago. So hopefully you should have what you need now.